# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user", :id=>nil}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, routes

Hello everybody, I have this problem (title of the post).

```
Failure/Error: get :create, :user => { :email => 'foo@example.com', :name => 'userexample' }
ActionController::RoutingError:No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user", :id=>nil}
```

Here is my `UserController`.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.save
    redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @user.id
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  root :to => "user#index"
  resources :user
  #match "newuser" => "user#new"
  get "user/new"
  post "user/create"
  get "user/:id" => "user#show"
```

And here is my rspec test

```
require 'spec/spec_helper'

describe UserController do
  it "create new user" do
    get :create, :user => { :email => 'foo@example.com', :name => 'userexample' }
      flash[:notice] = 'new user was successfully created.'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if @user.save
   redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @user.id
else
 ...
end
```

Comment: To explain a little more, you will be redirected to show even if .save fails, thus you are being redirected, and the value of @user.id is nil.

Comment: i put that you recommended, but now i get this error
    Failure/Error: get :create, :user => { :email => 'foo@example.com', :name => 'userexample' }
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template user/create, application/create with     {:handlers=>[:coffee, :haml, :builder, :erb], :locale=>[:en],     :formats=>[:html]}. Searched in:

Comment: @ArmandoDeJesusSantoya That's because on the else, nothing is happening, so Rails is trying to find a create.html.haml (or .erb, whatever) file to render. What do you want to happen if the user creation fails? Maybe redirect back to the creation page? Then in your else, put `redirect_to new_user_path`.

Answer (score 1):

Most Rails apps use this type of content block for creating and updating records.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user, :notice => "User was created successfully."
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Basically, when the `create` action is run it creates a new record, or a new instance of the `User` model.

When `.save` is called it checks all the validations. If the validations pass then it returns true, else it returns false.

If it returns false, then you need to render the `:new` template again so person has a chance to fix any validation errors.

If it returns true, then you want to redirect to the `show` action. The cool thing about rails is that [it can automatically figure that out](http://ryanbigg.com/2012/03/polymorphic-routes/) by just passing the instance `@user`.

---

Ryan Bates has a tutorial on [testing controllers with RSpec](http://railscasts.com/episodes/71-testing-controllers-with-rspec). Based on what he does, this is how I would test your controller.

```
require 'spec/spec_helper'

describe UserController do

  describe "POST 'create'" do

    it "should redirect to user on successful save" do
      User.any_instance.stub(:valid?) { true }
      post :user
      flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
      assigns(:user).should_not be_a_new_record
      response.should redirect_to(assigns(:user))
    end

    it "should render new template on failed save" do
      User.any_instance.stub(:valid?) { false }
      post :user
      flash[:notice].should be_nil
      assigns(:user).should be_a_new_record
      response.should render_template(:new)
    end

    it "should pass params" do
      User.any_instance.stub(:valid?) { true }
      post :user, :user => { email_address: "baylor@example.com" }
      assigns(:user).email_address.should == "baylor@example.com"
    end
  end
end
```