# Trying to create user sessions -- > No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

after finishing Michael Hart's tutorial on rails, I'm giving making a simple app of my own a try.

I managed to create the users resource, and am now trying to create a sessions resource, to track when someone is logged in. I'm getting some really wacky results.

1) I was trying to display different menu options for when someone is logged in, and for when someone is logged out. It works, except it behaves the opposite to the way I expected it ! i.e when I write

```
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <% if signed_in? %>
               #menu for registered users
          <% else %>
               #menu for unregistered users             
          <% end %>
        </ul>
```

When I'm logged in, the #menu for unregistered users shows up, and when I'm logged out, the #menu for registered users shows up.

2) I'm also trying to create a link to the user's admin page, which is the basically the user's id page.

I put this as the following as the link code

```
<%= link_to "Admin", user_path(current_user) %>
```

And got the error

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}

This makes me think that the current_user I defined in the sessions helper is not being saved, but than I think, but I'm not sure why.

Here's the code I have for the 
**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  private

        def create_remember_token
          self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
        end

end
```

**Sessions Controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid Email/Password Combination' #Not quite right; 
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

end

**SessionsHelper**

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
end
```

**ApplicationController**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Your current_user is nil. Check why your current_user is null. May be session variable is not set at the the of login

Comment: Hi Mohit, thanks for the comment
 > May be session variable is not set at the the of login

How would I check that?

Comment: Throw a debugger in your create method and look at what the `session` variable has available.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! It seemed like I had two errors --

1) I didn't sign in users when they registered in the users controller

and 2) I didn't restart the server, and do a db:reset. After trying that, the other problems, having to do with the signout not working, fixed.

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11545078/1297435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys! It seemed like I had two errors -- 1) I didn't sign in users when they registered in the users controller and 2) I didn't restart the server, and do a db:reset. After trying that, the other problems, having to do with the signout not working, fixed.